# Specfic epubs downloaded outside the iBooks store not syncing on a particular mac

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac, icloud, books

I have a handful of epubs I downloaded outside of the iBooks Store and read them across two different macs and an iPhone.

For reasons I cannot explain some books’ data  (highlights, notes, place in book) will sync across the devices while others do not.

The following options are turned on in my iPhone settings:

- Sync Bookmarks and Notes
- Sync Collections

On both macs I have the following turned on:

- Sync bookmarks, highlights, collections across devices

I have not used syncing via iTunes. So some books sync via iCloud while others do not.

Despite syncing turned on, I cannot get a Macbook Pro to sync with the highlights on the iPhone for certain book. I drag the epub into iBooks on the Macbook and it thinks its a “new” book. FWIW, I have a Mac Mini that seems to sync fine.

How can I correct this?

**Hardware:**

Macbook Pro 
Intel Core i7 3.1 Ghz 
OS X 10.11.4

Mac Mini
2.3 GHz quad-core Intel Core i7
OS X 10.11.4

iPhone SE 64GB
iOS 9.3.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good news is that you aren't alone. I spent 2 hours with a Senior Applecare Adviser about this exact issue. It's also obnoxiously inconsistent. I've seen data go up from one unit but not to anything else. iOS devices and OS X devices seem totally separated. There's currently a ticket in for Apple Engineering for the situation. If I learn more, I'll make sure to post it here.

Comment: I also have this very same problem.

Comment: I have tried the various recommendations like activating / deactivating iBooks iCloud syncing as well as 'Sync bookmarks, highlights, collections across devices', restarting devices, but syncing highlights & collections never works reliably across Mac, iPad and iPhone. iOS version 10.2 & Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Go to system preferences-> icloud -> icloud drive options...

Then look for ibook entry, check it. Done

[image]